# Django override save for model only in some cases?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Before saving `Model` instance I need to re-size `image`. How can I check if new picture added or just description updated? So I can skip rescaling every time the model is saved.

```
class Model(model.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='folder')
    thumb=models.ImageField(upload_to='folder')
    description=models.CharField()


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.image:
            small=rescale_image(self.image,width=100,height=100)
            self.image_small=SimpleUploadedFile(name,small_pic)
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want to rescale only if new image loaded or image updated, but not when description updated.

Comment: Are you resizing to a fixed size of 100x100?

Comment: U may find [django-imagekit](http://bitbucket.org/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/wiki/Home) useful

Comment: Also see notes in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Some thoughts:

```
class Model(model.Model):
    _image=models.ImageField(upload_to='folder')
    thumb=models.ImageField(upload_to='folder')
    description=models.CharField()

    def set_image(self, val):
        self._image = val
        self._image_changed = True

        # Or put whole logic in here
        small = rescale_image(self.image,width=100,height=100)
        self.image_small=SimpleUploadedFile(name,small_pic)

    def get_image(self):
        return self._image

    image = property(get_image, set_image)

    # this is not needed if small_image is created at set_image
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if getattr(self, '_image_changed', True):
            small=rescale_image(self.image,width=100,height=100)
            self.image_small=SimpleUploadedFile(name,small_pic)
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Not sure if it would play nice with all pseudo-auto django tools (Example: ModelForm, contrib.admin etc).

Comment: Looks nice. But i cant  rename image to _image. Is that important?

Comment: Ok i solved it with db_column='image'. But it steel not works!

Comment: It very interesting method.. by i dont understand it fully. Can you please explain it more explicatively? Or sow some article?

Comment: It is not worked for me too,. set_image never called. Looks like this some Django not officially supported stuff

Answer (score 27):

Check the model's pk field.  If it is None, then it is a new object.

```
class Model(model.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='folder')
    thumb=models.ImageField(upload_to='folder')
    description=models.CharField()


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'form' in kwargs:
            form=kwargs['form']
        else:
            form=None

        if self.pk is None and form is not None and 'image' in form.changed_data:
            small=rescale_image(self.image,width=100,height=100)
            self.image_small=SimpleUploadedFile(name,small_pic)
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Edit: I've added a check for 'image' in form.changed_data.  This assumes that you're using the admin site to update your images.  You'll also have to override the default save_model method as indicated below.

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save(form=form)
```

Comment: I think you're right...assuming he's using the admin site, he can override the save_model in his AdminModel to pass the form through to save, and check if 'image' is in form.changed_data.  I'll update as soon as I get time.

Comment: This only works if the object is new as you say. If you upload a new picture the rescaling won't trigger.

Comment: "self.pk is None" does not work if one specifies the id, so: Model.objects.get_or_create(id=234,...)  will not work in this solution

Answer (score 10):

You may supply extra argument for confirming a new image is posted.
Something like:

```
def save(self, new_image=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if new_image:
        small=rescale_image(self.image,width=100,height=100)
        self.image_small=SimpleUploadedFile(name,small_pic)
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

or pass request variable

```
def save(self, request=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if request and request.FILES.get('image',False):
        small=rescale_image(self.image,width=100,height=100)
        self.image_small=SimpleUploadedFile(name,small_pic)
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I think these wont break your save when called simply.

You may put this in your admin.py so that this work with admin site too (for second of above solutions):

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ....
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): 
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save(request=request)
        return instance
```

Comment: it tell me that: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'FILE'

Comment: sry its FILES instead of FILE, updated to request.FILES.get('image',False) instead of request.FILES['image'], this will avoid the exception

Answer (score 4):

Query the database for an existing record with the same PK. Compare the file sizes and checksums of the new and existing images to see if they're the same.

Answer (score 4):

What I did to achieve the goal was to make this..

```
# I added an extra_command argument that defaults to blank
def save(self, extra_command="", *args, **kwargs):
```

and below the save() method is this..

```
# override the save method to create an image thumbnail
if self.image and extra_command != "skip creating photo thumbnail":
    # your logic here
```

so when i edit some fields but not editing the image, I put this..

```
Model.save("skip creating photo thumbnail")
```

you can replace the `"skip creating photo thumbnail"` with `"im just editing the description"` or a more formal text.

Hope this one helps!

Answer (score -1):

In new version it is like this:

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    has_unknown_fields = set(self.initial_data) - set(self.fields.keys())
    if has_unknown_fields:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Do not send extra fields")
    return attrs
```

Answer (score -2):

I have found one another simple way to store the data into the database

models.py

```
class LinkModel(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    shortLink = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
```

In database I have only 2 variables

views.py

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = LinkForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.cleaned_data['link'] # text for link

        dbobj = LinkModel()
        dbobj.link = text
        self.no = self.gen.generateShortLink() # no for shortLink
        dbobj.shortLink = str(self.no)
        dbobj.save()         # Saving from views.py
```

In this I have created the instance of model in views.py only and putting/saving data into 2 variables from views only.