# Caching query results in django

Tags: django, caching

I'm trying to find a way to cache the results of a query that won't change with frequency. For example, categories of products from an e-commerce (cellphones, TV, etc).
I'm thinking of using the template fragment caching, but in this fragment, I will iterate over a list of these categories. This list is avaliable in any part of the site, so it's in my `base.html` file. Do I have always to send the list of categories when rendering the templates? Or is there a more dynamic way to do this, making the list always available in the template?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Pop your cached query into [Django's cache](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api):

```
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set('key', queryset)
```

Then create a context processor to add the value of the cache to all templates:

```
# myproject/myapp/context_processors.py

from django.core.cache import cache

def cached_queries():
    return {'cache', cache.get('key')}
```

Then add your context processor in your [Django settings file](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors):

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
    'myproject.myapp.context_processors.cached_queries'
)
```

Now you will be able to access the `cache` variable in all generic templates and all templates which have a requests context, which a template is given if this is done in the view:

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### When to Set the Cache

It depends on what is contained in the cache. However a common problem is that Django only really gets to execute Python whenever a page request is sent, and this is often not where you want to do this kind of work.

An alternative is to create a [custom management command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) for a particular app. You can then either run this manually when necessary, or more commonly set this to run as a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

To create a management command you must create a class decended from `Command` inside of a `management/commands` directory located inside of an app:

```
# myproject/myapp/management/commands/update_cache.py

from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
from django.core.cache import cache

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = 'Refreshes my cache'

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        cache.set('key', queryset)
```

The name of this file is important as this will be the name of the command. In this case you can now call this on the command line:

```
python manage.py update_cache
```

Comment: I didn't know about context processors before, that wat the missing key.
What is the best place to set the cache? I'm thinking of extending the model's manager, so everywhere I need to get this list, I will avoid a hit in the database.

Comment: Another way to do this is to cache just the page fragment where I iterate the list.

Comment: @Marcio I have updated the end of my answer to include **When to Set the Cache**. It suggests using a Django management command to to this work, and then using a cron job to run it automatically every so often (maybe once a day)

Comment: Nice answer. An other elegant way to update the cache is to **override the model's save method** [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-override-save-for-model) to include the `cache.set()`

Comment: Very cool answer, in addition you will need to set your cache binding preferences in the ```settings.py``` file using the ```CACHES``` setting, see more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/)

Answer (score 16):

You can also use [johnny-cache](http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/) for automatic caching of querysets. It will (by default) cache all querysets, but you can force it not to cache some.

Comment: Johnny-cache isn’t supported anymore, use [django-cachalot](http://django-cachalot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead.