# How to cache a Django Model in Memory

Tags: python, django, caching, django-models

i have a Model in my app, that is used so much in my application, some views made something like 100 queries in that Table, I already have a tons of optimisations to make a better use of this Model, but the great part of that amount is caused by the Django **init** method of other classes, for personal reasons...
So actual i just put a global variable to store all the objects of that Model in there, so when i create or delete a one object from that Model I just reload that List... but i dont want to use cache machines like Memcached or Redis... i just want to store that QuerySet result in the Memory... And i want to still use the Managers in this cached Queryset.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [Django's provided caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631865/caching-query-results-in-django/4632043#4632043) to a very similar question gets you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest implementing a custom model manager and a query set. A django cache backend doesn't have to be memcached or redis it can be localmemory also, although I would advise you to stand up a real cache backend. We mostly have been using https://github.com/jmoiron/johnny-cache for this purpose but found it is not compatible with django > 1.6 so we are switching over to https://github.com/vijaykatam/django-cache-manager