# Django - Filter a queryset by Max(date) year

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I would like to know if I can get in a single query, All the objects of certain model where its date's year equals the year of the Max('date') of the model. For example, using the models from the [Aggregation Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/), how can I get All the `Book`s published in the year of the more recently published `Book`?

All the examples in the docs filter by immediate values (`pubdate__year=2006`), but I need to use a calculated value over the same object in the same query.

Of course, I could do this by performing two queries: one for getting the max year, and a second one to filter by that year, but I think it should be possible to do it in a single query. It's just I haven't figured it out yet.

Thanks for your help!

### EDIT:

Since some of you have given similar answers, I'm writing this update so my problem can be better understood.

This is my model:

```
class Expo(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name= _('Expo')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Expos')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    bio = models.ForeignKey(Bio, related_name='expos')
```

I need **"All the `Expo`s that happened in the latest year of the list of `Expo`s stored in my database"**

To resolve this, I'm doing this:

```
from django.db.models import Max
max_year = Expo.objects.all().aggregate(Max('date'))['date__max'].year
expos = Expo.objects.filter(date__year=max_year)
```

But this, I understand that performs two queries on the database. I would like an expression  that let me get the same result, but performing a single query.

I've tried as suggested:

```
Expo.objects.annotate(max_year=Max('date__year')).filter(date__year=F('max_year'))
```

But get the error:

```
FieldError: Join on field 'date' not permitted. Did you misspell 'year' for the lookup type?
```

I also have tried:

```
Expo.objects.annotate(max_date=Max('date')).filter(date__year__gte=F('max_date__year'))
```

but I get the error:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'max_date' into field. Choices are: bio, date, id, items, name, place, max_date
```

Notice that it says that it can't resolve `'max_date'`, but it appears listed among the choices. Weird.

Again, Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? In case you have problems finding the docs, here's an example of pretty much exactly what you are trying to do: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations

Comment: It should be noted that you have to use it in combination with the `F()` expression: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model

Comment: Thanks! The `F()` object seems to be what I need, but the bigger problem is that I need to compare the years, not the dates. I tried as suggested in the answer below: `Expo.objects.annotate(max_date=Max('date')).filter(date__gte=F('max_date'))` (note the `__gte`) but it returned not expected instances (with dates before the max date). I also tried `Expo.objects.annotate(max_date=Max('date')).filter(date__year__gte=F('max_date__year'))`, but got this bizarre error: `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'max_date' into field. Choices are: bio, date, id, items, name, place, max_date`

Comment: Performing statement in a **single query don't will improve performance**. Also, remember than, instead `Max` agregation you can get first model sorting by `-date`. For me it is more clear, readable and fast splitting code in two sentences. If you don't believe it, try to write your query in a single SQL brand agnostic sentence.

Comment: @danihp: Could you please explain me why it won't improve performance? That is precisely what worries me. Thanks!

Comment: Throoze, answered in my own answer. I hope it is useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Performing statement in **a single query is no guarantee to improve performance**, this is easy to understand if you try to write an agnostic RDBMS brand SQL single sentence for yours requirements. Also, you **lost in readability**.

In my opinion, you can see and elegant solution in this approach:

1. Get last `Expo` by date .
2. Do a simple filter query.

**For your code:**

```
max_year = Expo.objects.latest('date').date.year
expos = Expo.objects.filter(date__year=max_year)
```

Remember you can **[cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631865/caching-query-results-in-django)** max_year, also create a `DESC` index over `date` can helps.

Comment: Thanks! this was what I was concerned about when asked the question. That thing with the cache and the context processor, is also a very good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do something using a combination of [Annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) and [F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) object

To filter on Max date:

```
ModelClass.objects.annotate(max_date=Max('pubdate')).filter(pubdate=F('max_date'))
```

To filter on the year of Max date:

```
max_date = ModelClass.objects.latest("pubdate").pubdate
published_objs = ModelClass.objects.filter(pubdate__year=max_date.year)
```

There does not seem to be a way to filter on *Max(date.year)* in a single query. And as mentioned by @danihp, even a single query is not a guarantee of performance.

Comment: hi! after testing your suggestion it doesn't seem to return what I'm expecting. First, what you're suggesting should return the objects whose fields `date` are equal to the `max_date`, and I need the objects whose fields `date`'s year are equal to the `max_date` year. Second, when I tested it in the `manage.py shell`, it returned (i think) all the objects, ignoring the filter. Did you test it? did it work for you? thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated the answer to filter on the year as well. The answer is based on my understanding of django (Untested because I don't have a setup similar to yours)

Comment: This will raise: `FieldError: Join on field 'pubdate' not permitted. Did you misspell 'year' for the lookup type?` on django 1.6. Please, test before post.

Comment: Please, fix your answer and notice me in order to remove my down vote.

Comment: @danihp I took a reference from [django 1.6 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#year). Can you please let me know the mistake, as I still don't understand the reason of the error.

Comment: `__year`, as appears in your link, is under [Field lookups section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups): *"Field lookups are how you specify the meat of an SQL WHERE clause. They’re specified as keyword arguments to the QuerySet methods filter(), exclude() and get()."* ;)

Comment: @danihp Edited the answer accordingly. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Do we have any function for old date? How do I find old date row?

Answer (score 2):

Throoze try this...

```
 queryset=Expo.objects.annotate(max_date=Max('date'))
 queryset1=queryset.values().filter(date__gte=F('max_date'))
```

Comment: Hi! It should have parenthesis after `values()`, and for some strange reason it also returns values with dates lesser than the max_date. And, as commented above, if I try to compare the years (which is what I need) , I keep getting this error: `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'max_date' into field. Choices are: bio, date, id, items, name, place, max_date`. Thanks anyways for your help :)

Comment: Do we have any function for old date?