# translate the SQL query to django model

Tags: django

I have a SQL query :

```
   Select * From Order a Where date = (Select Max(b.date) From Order b Where a.company = b.company)
```

How to translate it into Django way using the Django ORM?

Model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    id            = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    company       = models.ForeignKey('company', on_delete =models.CASCADE, null=False)
    text          = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)                      
    date          = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Comment: check this ans:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723512/django-filter-a-queryset-by-maxdate-year

Comment: can you add the models you have?

Comment: Please post models content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to get each companies `Order` object with the maximum date? You could try

```
Order.objects.all().order_by('-date').distinct('company')
```

This should order by the queryset date descending and return the first distinct companies

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is run the query using raw:

```
order.objects.raw("Select * From Order a Where date = (Select Max(b.date) From Order b Where a.company = b.company)")
```

please check these docs below:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields