# Preventing a Django user from creating more than N items

Tags: django, validation

Part of my business model dictates that a certain type of user cannot create more than a certain number of "things".

Let me explain with some pseudo-code:

```
class Thing(Model):
     owner = ForeignKey(User)
```

Where is the appropriate place to validate a `Form`, so that the user can't create the `nth + 1` thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add it to the form's [`clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) method:

```
class ThingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cleaned_data = super(ThingForm, self).clean()
        owner = cleaned_data.get("owner")
        other_things_count = Things.objects.filter(owner=owner).count()
        if other_things_count >= 20:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Too many things!")
        return cleaned_data
```

Alternatively you could [overwrite the models `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods), or you could create a [signal that is fired on `pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save), but neither of these will allow you tie validation messages to the form, so I think the `clean()` method above is best.

**EDIT** If you want to exclude editing, you can check to see if the `ModelForm` has an `instance`, i.e. an existing object

```
other_things_count = Things.objects.filter(owner=owner).exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).count()
```

Comment: Doesn't this fail when the user has 20 things, and wants to *edit* an existing thing?

Comment: typo. Should be `>=`. I've changed it. It's just an example, the condition can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider raise an exception in one of this places:

- [Overwriting save method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-overwrite-save-for-model)
- Binding code to [pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save)
- In each form that model appears with [clean form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)
- In [model clean method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) (my favorite method).

Sample code to raise exception:

```
if myThing.pk is None and myThing.owner.thing_set.count() > n:
     # here raise your exception:
     raise ValidationError("Too many things!")
```