# django model field update on a special event

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.6

If I define `auto_now = True` on a DateTimeField, than this field will be updated on every save(). But, how to update this field when something special happened?

For example: update DateTimeField only if some other field of the same Model has changed its state. Of course, I can define a trigger on a DB level, or catch pre_save or post_save signals to make stuff. But is there a way to do it another manner?

Comment: I thing that pre_save or save or post_save are best solution for this issue. If i make it, i will implement save method of model. (Sorry for bad english)

Comment: You can override `model.save` method and change `DateTime` field to `now`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-override-save-for-model

Comment: Thanks guys. It seems the most appropriate solution for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `django-models-utils` and use it's [`MonitorField`](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#monitorfield). It's a DateTimeField subclass that monitors another field on the model, and updates itself to the current date-time whenever the monitored field changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'update_fields' argument of the save() method:

```
# Write your logic to check if the fields or field has changed, then:
model.save(update_fields=['field1', 'field2'])  # Do not include the DateTimeField if you don't want it updated.
```