# Override save method of Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Well, I want to save any instance of a model without taking care about DDBB structure. So I decide to override `def save` in every model´s class. Kind of:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    if condition:
        raise Exception("You can´t insert that element")
    return super(name_class, self).save(self, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
```

Well, with this I achieve to insert not raising an exception, but if the instance passes this check I want to insert in the DB whatever primary restriction exists...

How can I get it?

I suppose I must have to override the core code of `save`, but I checked it and I didn't find the part where I check the conditions for inserting in the DB.
Maybe, The problem is only in the validation of the form.

How can I override a specific form in Django Admin? Specifically, that one where I add, Delete or Edit one class of the model.

Comment: You can overwrite save method of model. Here is example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-override-save-for-model

Comment: Thanks Lam, but that is what I´m doing. Check my post at the beginning. The problem is not extends save, It´s to override it.
My models has a primary key restriction, but the real DB doesnt (even it looks that it hasn´t sense, it has... :P). I mean, if datas pass my own check I want to forces the insert (is_valid=True maybe...)
My two approaches are: overriding save (not extends it) or jump validations on the forms

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can overwrite [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) of `ModelAdmin`.

```
class MyAdminView(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: The very first thing in the docs above [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods) is a warning stating it is "not for veto purposes"

Comment: I didn´t check, I guess will be the same. With that I´m extending the method. When I call the parent it will do the same which it suppose to do. Check PK restriction I deny the inserting.

Comment: Yeah. I did it. When I am trying to add a new element a primary key restriction warning appears. I override save_model, for recover fields of request in a obj and save the obj.
The priamry key restriction is checked in other part. I dont know when I´m saving (save(), save_model(),...) or in validation phase (clean(), validate(),...). Any clues?

Comment: how to add a flag for commit false ?

Comment: Fixed link from @Sayse regarding [the warning when not to apply model changes in `save_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods).