# Django model instance custom method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to integrate a custom method on a Django model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = MarkdownField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def generate_unique_slug(self):
        slug = self._meta.get_field('slug')
        max_length = slug.max_length
        slug = orig = slugify(self.title)[:max_length]

        for x in itertools.count(1):
            if not Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
                break

            # Truncate the original slug dynamically. Minus 1 for the hyphen.
            slug = "%s-%d" % (orig[:max_length - len(str(x)) - 1], x)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.generate_unique_slug()
        self.save()
```

When called from "publish", "generate_unique_slug" doesn't work. For example, I'll do this from terminal

```
>>> p = Post(title="Title Example", text="Text example")
>>> p.publish()
>>> p.title
'Title Example'
>>> p.published_date
datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 18, 14, 45, 12, 710452, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> p.slug
u''
```

I've also tried this

```
>>> p.generate_unique_slug()
>>> p.slug
u''
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not updating the `slug` of your model. Add `self.slug = slug` at the end of `generate_unique_slug`:

```
def generate_unique_slug(self):
    # your code
    self.slug = slug
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! Anyway, when I create the Post from the admin panel, the slug isn't created: any thoughts on how I might get that?

Comment: The slug is generated only when you run the publish function. Is this where your problem is? If so, you probably want to override the save method.

Comment: Because the method will not be called when creating a new `Post`. You can modify the save method of your model to always call  `generate_unique_slug`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-override-save-for-model)

Comment: Thank you. I made it by overriding the save method, and putting "super(Post, self).save()" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`generate_unique_slug` neither change any instance attribute nor return anything.

You should change `slug` in `slug = "%s-%d" % (orig[:max_length - len(str(x)) - 1], x)` to `self.slug = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not fix your code, but I think it is a good option as it covers multiple cases.

There is a library called [uuslug](https://github.com/un33k/django-uuslug) designed to do exactly this. It might be worth checking out.

A example from the repository:

```
from django.db import models
from uuslug import uuslug

# Override your object's save method with something like this (models.py)
class CoolSlug(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = uuslug(self.name, instance=self)
        super(CoolSlug, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

name = "john"
c = CoolSlug.objects.create(name=name)
c.save()
print(c.slug) # => "john"

c1 = CoolSlug.objects.create(name=name)
c1.save()
print(c1.slug) # => "john-1"
```

I also believe you can change `slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)` to `slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)`, and it would still work properly.

**Edit after comment:**

Instead of overriding `save`, you could do the following:

```
from uuslug import slugify

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = MarkdownField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.slug = slugify(self.title, max_length=self._meta.get_field('slug'))
        self.save()
```

Does this fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the library, anyway I think you misread the line, as the slug line is "slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)" :)