# Duplicate an ImageField in another field of same model while saving the model objects

Tags: django-models, copy, duplicates, imagefield

I want to upload one image(location of which stores in `photo` field of model mentioned below ) and I want to duplicate that photo to another field `thumbnail` programmatically.

I tried in the way mentioned in `class Picture(models.Model):` below. Bytheway `ResizedImageField` works and i have tested it only for the `photo` field. Help needed to overwrite the `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):` method mentioned below.

```
from django_resized import ResizedImageField

class Picture(models.Model):
    photo = ResizedImageField('photo', upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', size=[636,331])
    thumbnail = ResizedImageField('thumbnail', upload_to='thumbnail/%Y/%m/%d', size=[150, 100], blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.photo:
            self.thumbnail = ResizedImageField(self.photo)
            self.thumbnail.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the save method you are calling on `self.thumbnail.save()`, try this instead:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.photo:
        self.thumbnail = ResizedImageField(self.photo)
    super(Picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

you may find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-override-save-for-model) useful