# Autofill database column after form submission in django

Tags: ajax, django, database, django-models, django-forms

Using Django 2.0 I have a model class named `Book` that asks for `title`, `author`, `year` but I have another column in that row that requires for a unique id based on the authors name, book title, and random numbers. This is my model

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    identification = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    holder = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='book_holder', on_delete=models.PROTECT(), null=True, blank=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
    overdue = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
```

and it will be used in a form that only asks for the `title`, `author`, and `year` but what im looking for is how can i fill the `identification` column after the user submits the form. So for example if the user enters `Harry Potter` for the `title` and `J. K. Rowling` for the `author`, I want `identification` to have a value of a combination of both plus an eight digit random number at the end something like `JH28194637` but I also need this column to be unique for every book so if i had to of the same Harry Potter books, I would need both to be different so one could be `JH28194637` while the other one could be `JH39287104`. I will be using ajax to submit my form and I was thinking of maybe having a variable in my javascript that builds my `identification` when the user fills in the `author` and `title` fields and then passing it to my ajax call. Would that be the best way? But then how would I be able to check if the variable value already exists in the database or what would be the best way to do this task.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-override-save-for-model#4269828

Answer (score 1):

Since the two other fields are subject to change, and I assume that your identification field will also need to change, in terms of a unique integer you can always use that books model ID to make things simpler (unless you need to specify a particular id for certain books).

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    holder = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='book_holder', on_delete=models.PROTECT(), null=True, blank=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
    overdue = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    @property
    def identification():
        a = self.author[:1].upper()
        t = self.title[:1].upper()
        id = str(self.id.zfill(10))
        return a+t+id
```