# Count TextField characters with Django

Tags: django-models, python-3.6, counting, django-2.1

I've created [this simple counter](https://gist.github.com/MaxDragonheart/6d60209321108fddccc26ed2b147020b) with Python3.6 and I would like to do the same thing with a TextField in my models.

What interests me is the line 37 that is [here](https://gist.github.com/MaxDragonheart/6d60209321108fddccc26ed2b147020b); I want to transport it in Django.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70, help_text="Write post title here. The title must be have max 70 characters", verbose_name="Titolo", unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="Slug", unique="True", help_text="Slug is a field in autocomplete mode, but if you want you can modify its contents")
    tagline = models.TextField(max_length=200, help_text="Write a post short description here. The description must be have max 200 characters", verbose_name="Breve descrizione dell'articolo")
    contents = models.TextField(help_text="Write your post here", verbose_name="Contenuti")
    time_of_reading = models.IntegerField(count(contents) / 250)
    highlighted = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="If you want that the post went be highlighted, click on this area", verbose_name="Articolo in evidenza")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

With this I've this error:

```
  File "/var/www/html/dev/miosito/django/v2.1/versions/aproject/muletto/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Post(models.Model):
  File "/var/www/html/dev/miosito/django/v2.1/versions/aproject/muletto/models.py", line 10, in Post
    time_of_reading = models.IntegerField(count(contents) / 250)

NameError: name 'count' is not defined
```

I'm newbie into the development world

Comment: Where did you get this from? Does models.TextField have a count function? I suggest if you are a newbie you should stick to basic concepts. 
That said this is the bigger issue imo... Why are you wasting a space on a field that can be easily calculated at any time? I suggest you read about database normalization and why storing such fields is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think it's possible do the same thing with a javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is override method save().
In save() do something like that:

```
    self.thistime_of_reading = self.count(self.contents)
```

Here:
[Django. Override save for model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-override-save-for-model)

Comment: I must add a stuff like this in the model Post?
` def save(self):
        self.thistime_of_reading = count(self.contents)/250 `
If yes I've this error:
` File "/var/www/html/dev/miosito/django/v2.1/versions/aproject/muletto/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Post(models.Model):
  File "/var/www/html/dev/miosito/django/v2.1/versions/aproject/muletto/models.py", line 9, in Post
    time_of_reading = models.IntegerField(count(contents) / 250)

NameError: name 'count' is not defined`

Comment: You have to define, maybe in model, function count, and call it in save method.