# Django models: How to set up field value based on another field when new model item created in admin interface?

Tags: python, django, oop, django-models, django-2.1

I have two related models: `Plaint` and `WritOfExecutionTemplate`. It is possible to add new template on plaint edit page using `admin.TabularInline` class. When user create new template from plaint page, I need to fill 2 power of attorney (POA) fields based on current plaint. User allowed to change POAs before template will be saved.

[image]

I tried to set callback method to field`s `default` attribute, but I have problem getting referenced plaint object.

```py
class AbstractGeneratedCaseDocument(AbstractBaseModel):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    case = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name=_('case'),
        to='Case',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    power_of_attorney = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name=_('power of attorney'),
        to='ImportedDocument',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='+',
    )
    power_of_attorney_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name=_('power of attorney') + ' 2',
        to='ImportedDocument',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='+',
    )


class Plaint(AbstractGeneratedCaseDocument):
    pass


class WritOfExecutionTemplate(AbstractBaseModel, WhoDidItMixin):
    plaint = models.ForeignKey(
        to='Plaint',
        verbose_name=_('plaint'),
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )

    def get_poa1_from_plaint(self):
        if (self.plaint.power_of_attorney is not None
                and self.plaint.case.plaintiff_representative == self.plaint.power_of_attorney.relative_person):
            poa = self.plaint.power_of_attorney
        else:
            poa = None
        return poa

    def get_poa2_from_plaint(self):
        # The same as for the first power of attorney
        if (self.plaint.power_of_attorney_2 is not None
                and self.plaint.case.plaintiff_representative == self.plaint.power_of_attorney_2.relative_person):
            poa = self.plaint.power_of_attorney_2
        else:
            poa = None
        return poa

    power_of_attorney = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name=_('power of attorney'),
        to='ImportedDocument',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        #null=True,
        #blank=True,
        related_name='+',
        default=get_poa1_from_plaint,
    )

    power_of_attorney_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name=_('power of attorney') + ' 2',
        to='ImportedDocument',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='+',
        default=get_poa2_from_plaint
    )
```

Admin model:

```py
class WritOfExecutionTemplateAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = WritOfExecutionTemplate


class PlaintAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (
        WritOfExecutionTemplateAdminInline,
    )
```

Error message:

> get_poa1_from_plaint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

What is the right way to make what I need?

Comment: The defaults can *not* refer to a function that takes parameters (including `self`).

Comment: @willem-van-onsem I`ve got it. Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: what about custom save() method? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-override-save-for-model

Comment: There is not what I need. Because fields must be auto filled when user clicked on add button and he can change them before saving.