# Need help in asinging values for Choices in Choice Field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

**models.py**

```
class Survey_Answer(models.Model):
    
    CHOICES = [('Disagree Strongly', 'Disagree Strongly'),
            ('Disagree', 'Disagree'),
            ('Undecided', 'Undecided'),
            ('Agree', 'Agree'),
            ('Agree Strongly', 'Agree Strongly')]
    
    question = models.ForeignKey(Survey_Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHOICES, default='Undecided')
    date_published = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('created at', auto_now_add=True)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text + ' -  ' + self.question.question_text
```

This is my models.py. I need help in assigning value for a particular option in CHOICES( Eg: 5 points for Agree Strongly option). If a user selects an option from choices, he should be getting points based on the option he selected

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, please explain in  more detail.

Comment: You can use tuples as choices.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Sure...For Example, if a user selects "Agree Strongly" he should be getting a value of 5 points when selecting that option and on a scale of 5 to 1 point if he selects Disagree Strongly he should be getting 1 point

Comment: What are these points? Where are they stored? At which point are they awarded?

Comment: They are awarded based on the options in CHOICES...I am engaged in a survey project and there will be a list of questions where each option holds a certain value...If a user selects Agree in CHOICES he should be assigned a value of 3...I am using Django for the backend So need to give validation for these options in the backend

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use choices, you can use them as tuples.

```
CHOICES = (('Disagree Strongly', 'Disagree Strongly'),
        ('Disagree', 'Disagree'),
        ('Undecided', 'Undecided'),
        ('Agree', 'Agree'),
        ('Agree Strongly', 'Agree Strongly'))
```

Insted of `[]` use `()`.

Comment: Hi @ManojKamble Thanks for the suggestion but I need help in assigning values for those choices

Comment: Can you explain in more details?

Comment: Sure..For Example, if a user selects "Agree Strongly" he should be getting a value of 5 points when selecting that option and on a scale of 5 to 1 point if he selects Disagree Strongly he should be getting 1 point

Answer (score 0):

you can override the save method of the model.

```
class Survey_Answer(models.Model):

 def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
 **Do Stuff whatever you want** //Give points to users
 super(Survey_Answer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi, @ManojKamble I am new to Django... Can you give me an example pls

Comment: Check the article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-override-save-for-model

Comment: I have tried that @ManojKamble but it is not particular for Choicefield

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to achieve this. Either use choices tuple with your desired value or override save method of the model.

**1ST OPTION:**

```
class Survey_Answer(models.Model):
    
    CHOICES = (('Disagree Strongly', '1'),
            ('Disagree', '2'),
            ('Undecided', '3'),
            ('Agree', '4'),
            ('Agree Strongly', '5'))
    
    question = models.ForeignKey(Survey_Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHOICES, default='Undecided')
    date_published = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('created at', auto_now_add=True)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text + ' -  ' + self.question.question_text
```

It simply means user will select the left option(1st element of the tuple) and you can use the right option(2nd element of the tuple) for your processing. So if user selects 'Agree Strongly' you will have '5' value as well. You can then use serializers to show that value. The syntax for using this will be **get_your_field_display**.

**serializers.py file**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class SurveySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    value = serializers.Charfield(source = 'get_answer_text_display', read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Survey_Answer
        fields = ('question', 'answer_text', 'date_published', 'value') # assuming that you don't want users to see created at field
```

please note that **value** is a custom field in the serializer.

**2ND OPTION:**

2nd and preferred option would be to add another field in your model and override save method to add this value

**models.py**

```
class Survey_Answer(models.Model):
    
    CHOICES = (('Disagree Strongly', '1'),
            ('Disagree', '2'),
            ('Undecided', '3'),
            ('Agree', '4'),
            ('Agree Strongly', '5'))
    
    question = models.ForeignKey(Survey_Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHOICES, default='Undecided')
    date_published = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('created at', auto_now_add=True)
    value = models.IntegerField()


    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.value = # add your value based based on if else or above trick used in serializers
        super(Survey_Answer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text + ' -  ' + self.question.question_text
```

Comment: Can you give me a sample of what I should be defined in self.value in 2nd Option

Comment: self.answer_text_display()